# Uniq Descending Sort in a column

Tags: sort, uniq

In the given data is it possible to uniq sort and print only the top hits against each region?

Given Data

```
aza1 18
bcn1 16
sat2 12
lcy2 12
fra1 12
aza1 12
bcn1 10
sat2 8
lcy2 9
fra1 13
aza1 21
bcn1 2
sat2 10
lcy2 0
fra1 1
```

Required Output

```
aza1 21
bcn1 16
sat2 12
lcy2 12
fra1 13
```

Comment: Is the order important? it's easier to do if the first column can be in lexical order

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solution if order matters, using only *sort* and *uniq*

```
<INPUT_FILE sort -k 1,1 -k 2nr,2 | uniq -w4
```

OUTPUT:

```
aza1 21
bcn1 16
fra1 13
lcy2 12
sat2 12
```

**Sort parameters:**

-k: sort by key (in this case column, pairs with -t)

-n: sort as a number

-r: reverse order

(optional) -t: in case you want to change the key separator (default: space)

**Uniq parameter:**

-w: choose the first N characters

**Explanation:**

In your problem, we need to first sort the first column and then the second one. So there is a **-k 1,1** followed by **-k 2,2**. 
But, the second key **(ONLY)** must be sorted as a number and in the reverse order.
Thus, it should be **-k 2nr,2**.

Note that if the -n or -r sort parameters are outside -k parameter, they are applied to the whole input instead of specific keys.

Lastly, me must find the unique lines, but matching only the first 4 chars. Thus, **uniq -w 4**

Answer (score 0):

If the order doesn't matter:

```
<infile sort -rnk2,2  |sort -uk1,1
```

`-r`evers `-n`umerical `sort` on `-k`ey column number `2` (`sort -rnk2,2`), then keep and `-u`nique lines on first `-k`ey column (`sort -uk1,1`);

or same with `awk`:

```
<infile awk '
            { arr[$1]= (arr[$1]<$2)? $2 : arr[$1] }
         END{ for (x in arr) print x, arr[x] }'
```